# IntelliJ: show decompiled class disassembly even when source is present

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea, jvm, disassembly

IntelliJ can [display and debug decompiled classes](http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2015/02/debug-decompiled-code-with-intellij-idea-14-1/) when the sources cannot be found. Is there some way to force the debugger to use disassembly instead of sources even when the sources are found, other than deleting the sources?

This would be useful in a situation where the sources are wrong (do not match the class).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was added in IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1 (see [IDEA-144322](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-144322)) and is now available in the View menu next to Show Bytecode as Show Decompiled Class. It is available for library classes only, not for project classes.